# Null Pointer while converting to JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using WDCalendar in Struts2.
I was converting Hashmap to Json String using GSON, but all of a sudden, i am getting NULL pointer exception while conveting Hashmap to JSON String

```
result = new Gson().toJson(ret);
```

My Code :

```
public static String loadAllEvents(String start, String end) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps1 = null;
        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String result = "";
        Connection con = ULDBConnectionUtility.getDBConnection();
        HashMap<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();




        try{
            String strSql = "SELECT * FROM EVENT_MANAGER";// WHERE START_DATE BETWEEN '"+start+"' AND '"+end+"'";           
            ps1 = con.prepareStatement(strSql);
            rs1  = ps1.executeQuery();

            SimpleDateFormat fromDB = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            java.text.SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZ");


            ArrayList<ArrayList> eventArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
            while(rs1.next()){              
                ArrayList EvtData = new ArrayList();
                EvtData.add(rs1.getInt("EVENT_ID"));//0
                EvtData.add(rs1.getString("EVENT_TITLE"));//1
                EvtData.add(sourceFormat.format(fromDB.parse(rs1.getString("START_DATE"))));//2
                EvtData.add(sourceFormat.format(fromDB.parse(rs1.getString("END_DATE"))));//3
                EvtData.add(rs1.getInt("IS_ALL_DAY_EVENT"));//4
                EvtData.add(Integer.parseInt("0"));//5
                EvtData.add(rs1.getInt("RECURRING_RULE"));//6
                EvtData.add(rs1.getString("COLOR"));//7
                EvtData.add(Integer.parseInt("1"));//8
                EvtData.add(rs1.getString("LOCATION"));//9
                EvtData.add("");//10
                eventArrayList.add(EvtData);
            }
            String error = "";
             ret.put("events", eventArrayList);
             ret.put("issort", true);
             ret.put("start", sourceFormat.format(fromDB.parse(start)));
             ret.put("end", sourceFormat.format(fromDB.parse(end)));
             ret.put("error", error);
             System.out.println("ret : "+ret);
             result = new Gson().toJson(ret);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs1 != null) {
                    rs1.close();
                }
                if (ps1 != null) {
                    ps1.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

HashMap before passing to convertion:

```
{events=[[98, EvebtTitle, Mon Dec 03 2012 10:45:00 +0530, Wed Oct 17 2012 11:15:00 +0530, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NJ, ], [118, testDec, Wed Dec 05 2012 09:00:00 +0530, Wed Dec 05 2012 10:00:00 +0530, 0, 0, 0, null, 1, null, ], [67, Test45, Wed Dec 05 2012 10:30:00 +0530, Tue Oct 16 2012 11:00:00 +0530, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, NY, ], [119, sd, Tue Dec 04 2012 00:00:00 +0530, Tue Dec 04 2012 00:00:00 +0530, 1, 0, 0, null, 1, null, ], [78, Test, Fri Dec 07 2012 09:30:00 +0530, Mon Oct 15 2012 10:15:00 +0530, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, LA, ], [66, Event 2, Tue Dec 04 2012 10:00:00 +0530, Tue Oct 16 2012 10:30:00 +0530, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, CA, ]], start=Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 +0530, issort=true, end=Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 +0530, error=null}
```

Error:

```
20:49:15,597 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NullPointerException
20:49:15,599 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.serialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:443)
20:49:15,601 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.serialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:430)
20:49:15,604 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:128)
20:49:15,605 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:96)
20:49:15,606 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContextDefault.serialize(JsonSerializationContextDefault.java:47)
20:49:15,608 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.serialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:445)
20:49:15,609 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$CollectionTypeAdapter.serialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:430)
20:49:15,610 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:128)
20:49:15,611 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:96)
20:49:15,612 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContextDefault.serialize(JsonSerializationContextDefault.java:47)
20:49:15,613 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$MapTypeAdapter.serialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:509)
20:49:15,613 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.DefaultTypeAdapters$MapTypeAdapter.serialize(DefaultTypeAdapters.java:489)
20:49:15,614 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationVisitor.visitUsingCustomHandler(JsonSerializationVisitor.java:128)
20:49:15,615 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:96)
20:49:15,616 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContextDefault.serialize(JsonSerializationContextDefault.java:47)
20:49:15,617 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:269)
20:49:15,618 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:220)
20:49:15,618 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:200)
20:49:15,619 ERROR [STDERR]     at dao.UtilityDao.loadAllEvents(UtilityDao.java:174)
20:49:15,620 ERROR [STDERR]     at utility.CalendarUtility.loadAllList(CalendarUtility.java:64)
20:49:15,621 ERROR [STDERR]     at servlet.DataFeed.doGet(DataFeed.java:56)
20:49:15,622 ERROR [STDERR]     at servlet.DataFeed.doPost(DataFeed.java:97)
20:49:15,623 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
20:49:15,624 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
20:49:15,625 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
20:49:15,626 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
20:49:15,627 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
20:49:15,
```

Comment: maybe it doesn't support the null value you put in `ret.put("error", null);`  comment that line out and see if it makes a difference

Comment: @Sam: Well it was working fine before with the same piece of code, any how i ll try to pass string object instead of null...

Comment: The problem is not the `null` in the hashmap. Gson deals with it with no problem.

Comment: Yes changing the null to a string Object... didn't work

Comment: Just one guess: I think that the problem could be with the `ArrayList<ArrayList>`. Please, try to comment the line: `ret.put("events", eventArrayList);`

Comment: As a piece of advice. Consider programming to interfaces rather than to implementation. Replace your code with: Map<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>(); List<ArrayList> eventArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();

Comment: How do you know that your your HashMap is null and not any other object? Have you debugged your code? Are you sure about it?

Comment: The NPE occurs in the `Gson.toJson()`, and obviously `ret` is not null: `HashMap<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();`

Comment: @Renato Lochetti: it worked after commenting {ret.put("events", eventArrayList);} now am confused was the ArrayList<ArrayList> causing this problem, is there a way to resolve this

Comment: Please debug and tell us what causes the NPE.

Comment: Thank you all guys, especially thank you  Renato Lochetti

Comment: @Warrior: No problem! We are here to help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

Some of the events field values were NULL in DB and this was the Cause.

In `ret.put("events", eventArrayList);`

eventArrayList refers `ArrayList<ArrayList>` and few field values in `<ArrayList>` were NULL,

From above Ex: (Look into the Null value in inner arraylist which is at second index)

```
{events=[[98, EvebtTitle, Mon Dec 03 2012 10:45:00 +0530, Wed Oct 17 2012 11:15:00 +0530, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NJ, ], [118, testDec, Wed Dec 05 2012 09:00:00 +0530, Wed Dec 05 2012 10:00:00 +0530, 0, 0, 0, null, 1, null, ]]}
```

After removing the Null values from the inner ArrayList  things are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind about method

> public String toJson(Object src)

is [GSON documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object%29) which states *"This method should be used when the specified object is not a generic type. If the object is of generic type, use toJson(Object, Type) instead."*

Another thing is that the null pointer exception may be caused by any other object, not specifically the HashMap. It seems that you took it for granted, but I recommend debugging your code.